# Multiple exchanges in Pika/RabbitMQ

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I want to create multiple exchanges in RabbitMQ and have different callbacks to each exchange. Following the tutorial, I built an asynchronous consumer but it accepts only one kind of exchange and queue.
https://gist.github.com/Enether/3fe8779a120e849b52c4160b376e68b8

What is a good approach to create multiple exchanges?

My idea is either

- Create a new connection (new instance of the Consumer)

e.g

```
class OtherConsumerConnection(BaseRabbitMQConsumerConnection):
    """
    This class defines the needed variables to establish a RabbitMQ connection
    """
    EXCHANGE = 'other_exchange'
    EXCHANGE_TYPE = 'fanout'
    QUEUE = 'text'
    ROUTING_KEY = 'example.text'
NotificationsConsumerConnection(RABBITMQ_CONNECTION_URL, handlers.first_handler).run()
OtherConsumerConnection(RABBITMQ_CONNECTION_URL, handlers.other_handler).run()
```

- Somehow extend the logic to accept multiple exchanges, but that'll be messy

Is it a bad idea to issue multiple connections? What's the right approach here?